# How to convert object series to string series?

Tags: string, object

```
df = pd.read_csv("06.Master.csv")
df["column(str)"]= df["column"].astype('str')
df["column(str)"].head()
'64382' in df["column(str)"]
64382 in df["column(str)"]
```

I try to convert this object series to string, but it doesn't work.
As you see, after applying  #.astype('str'), all values are caught as an integer, not a string.

Even though I make a simple function that converts integer to string and use #.apply(function), the same as above.

What should I do?

[image]